# Oracle SQL query about only extracting certain items

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

So I have these three tables:

```
WORKERS( WNO, WNAME, ZIP, HDATE )

CUSTOMERS( CNO, CNAME, STREET, ZIP, PHONE )

ORDERS( ONO, CNO, WNO, RECEIVED, SHIPPED )
```

I want to find the workers who have **ONLY** made sales to customers who lives in the same zip code as the workers. Until now I have this code:

```
SELECT e.wno
FROM ORDERS o, CUSTOMERS c, WORKERS e
WHERE o.cno = c.cno AND o.wno = e.wno AND c.zip = e.zip
```

But this doesn't give the required answer. Can anyone help me with this? It would be great if you can help.

```
ONO      CNO         WNO RECEIVED  SHIPPED         CNO CNAME                   STREET                      ZIP     PHONE             WNO WNAME                     ZIP HDATE
1021     1111       1000 12-JAN-95 15-JAN-95       1111 Charles                123 Main St.                67226 316-636-5555       1000 Jones                   67226 12-DEC-95
1020     1111       1000 10-DEC-94 12-DEC-94       1111 Charles                123 Main St.                67226 316-636-5555       1000 Jones                   67226 12-DEC-95
1022     2222       1001 13-FEB-95 20-FEB-95       2222 Bertram                237 Ash Avenue              67226 316-689-5555       1001 Smith                   60606 01-JAN-92
1026     2222       1001 03-JAN-96 08-JAN-96       2222 Bertram                237 Ash Avenue              67226 316-689-5555       1001 Smith                   60606 01-JAN-92
1023     3333       1000 20-JUN-97                 3333 Barbara                111 Inwood St.              60606 316-111-1234       1000 Jones                   67226 12-DEC-95
1024     4444       1002 13-APR-95 17-APR-95       4444 Jorge                  131 State St.               47907 765-111-1884       1002 Brown                   50302 01-SEP-94
1025     4444       1000 25-APR-95 30-APR-95       4444 Jorge                  131 State St.               47907 765-111-1884       1000 Jones                   67226 12-DEC-95
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your original query will work with the addition of just a `NOT EXISTS` clause:

```
SELECT e.wno
  FROM workers e, orders o, customers c
 WHERE e.wno = o.wno
   AND o.cno = c.cno
   AND c.zip = e.zip
   AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM orders o1, customers c1
                     WHERE o1.wno = e.wno
                       AND o1.cno = c1.cno
                       AND c1.zip != e.zip );
```

That is, get all of the workers who have delivered to customers in their own zip code but who have not delivered outside their zip code. You may wish to use ANSI joins as well (I have to admit that I'm not as comfortable with this syntax so I'm not 100% certain that the joins are correct):

```
SELECT e.wno
  FROM workers e INNER JOIN orders o
    ON e.wno = o.wno
 INNER JOIN customers c
    ON o.cno = c.cno
 WHERE c.zip = e.zip
   AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM orders o1 INNER JOIN customers c1
                        ON o1.cno = c1.cno
                     WHERE o1.wno = e.wno
                       AND c1.zip != e.zip );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT e.wno
FROM ORDERS o join  CUSTOMERS c on o.cno = c.cno
join WORKERS e on o.wno = e.wno
Group by e.wno,c.zip
having count(*)=1
```

Comment: Actually it doesn't work, it gives me two answers and when I check the data both of them have made sales to customers who lives in different zip codes but they have also made sales to customers who live in the same zip code also.

Comment: @user3690321 Can you add sample data?

Comment: I have added the data

Comment: looks a lot better now

Comment: @user3690321 Have changed my answer. please check.

Comment: Still gives the wrong answer. The query shouldn't display anything.

Comment: Can you make a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/), so that i can check and correct my query.

Answer (score 0):

One way is finding all the workers who sold a product on different zip then their and then do a minus (or NOT IN).

```
SELECT e.wno
FROM WORKERS e
WHERE e.wno NOT IN (
    SELECT e.wno
    FROM ORDERS o, CUSTOMERS c, WORKERS e
    WHERE o.cno = c.cno AND o.wno = e.wno AND c.zip != e.zip)
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be below query will help you :)

```
select * from WORKERS WR,CUSTOMERS CR,ORDERS OR 
where 
WR.ZIP=OR.ZIP
AND CR.CNO=OR.CNO
AND WR.WNO=OR.WNO
AND OR.RECEIVED is not null;
```

"OR.RECEIVED is not null" is condition to make sure the customer has received his/her item.